# How to search a query on another query result using cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a table with name 'test', like this:

> ---------------------------
>   id  |   name  |  others 
>   ---------------------------
>    1   |  wang   |  No.1 
>    2   |  zhang  |  No.1 
>    3   |   zhao   |  No.2 
>   ---------------------------

I want to group the field of 'others', and then search the name with 'wang' and 'zhang'. I can use mysql to realize it like this:

```
select others, name2 
from (select *, group_concat(name separator ',') as name2
      from test where 1=1 group by others) as sub 
where name2 like '%wang%' and name2 like '%zhang%'
```

So, my question is how to realize this using cakephp with find or paginate?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do this in cakehp, but a better way to write your query is:

```
select others, group_concat(name separator ',') as name2
from test
group by others
having sum(name = 'wang') > 0 and
       sum(name = 'zhang') > 0;
```

This will also prevent confusion.  Your version will return true for `kwang,zhangke`.  If you actually want this behavior, then use `like` instead:

```
select others, group_concat(name separator ',') as name2
from test
group by others
having sum(name like '%wang%') > 0 and
       sum(name like '%zhang%') > 0;
```

Comment: I think I have solved my question according to your code. Thank you very much!